# Segmentation fault in a linked list

Tags: c++, list

I am trying to make a programme for polynomials. I add an element to  polynomial using the addTerm function.There appears to be a segfault in the first "else" part of the function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
class Polynomial{
 protected:
  class Term{
  public:
    int exponent;
    int coefficient;
    Term *next;
    Term(int exp, int coeff,Term *n){
      exponent = exp;
      coefficient = coeff;
      next=n;
    };
    friend class Polynomial;
   };
   Term *head;
 public:
 Polynomial(){
  head=nullptr;
  head->next=nullptr;
 }
 Polynomial(const Polynomial &p){
  head=nullptr;
  Term* curr=p.head;
  while(curr!=nullptr){
    addTerm(curr->exponent,curr->coefficient);
    curr=curr->next;
  }
   }
 ~Polynomial(){
  Term* curr=head;
  while(curr!=nullptr){
    Term* next=curr->next;
    delete curr;
    curr=next;
  }
  head=nullptr;
  };

  Polynomial & operator = (const Polynomial &p){
  Term* curr=head;
  while(curr!=nullptr){
    Term* next=curr->next;
    delete curr;
    curr=next;
  }
  head=nullptr;
  Term* current=p.head;
  while(current!=nullptr){
    addTerm(current->exponent,current->coefficient);
    current=current->next;
  }
  return *this;

};

void addTerm(int expon, int coeff){
  if(head==nullptr){                              //adeia lista
    Term* t=new Term(expon,coeff,nullptr);
    head=t;
    // cout<<t->exponent<<t->coefficient;
  }
  else{
    if(expon>head->exponent){                  
      Term* temp= new Term(expon,coeff,head);
      temp->next=head;
      head=temp;
    }
    else{

     Term* current=head;
      for(current=head;expon!=current->exponent;current=current->next){
        if(current==nullptr) break;
      }
      if(current->exponent==expon){
        current->coefficient=current->coefficient+coeff;
      }
      else{
        current=head;
        Term* prev=head;
        while(expon<current->exponent){

         prev=current;
          current=current->next;
       }
        Term* temp=new Term(expon,coeff,current);
        prev->next=temp;
     }
}
}
```

The code I run it on is:

```
int main(){
 Polynomial p;
 p.addTerm(3,1);
 p.addTerm(2,3);
 }
```

Comment: `if(current->exponent==expon){` is a bug because `current` can be a nullptr.

Comment: @drescherjm you're right but the code still had a segfault when i removed that part of the code

Comment: May be, you should debug it step by step to find out if there is another issue. Inspecting the core (call stack) after crash is an option as well. Sometimes the bug can be found just in one of the calling functions.

Comment: @drescherjm The formation of the linked list is in the Polynomial() constructor.I believe all relevant code has been enclosed, I only skipped some friend functions.

Comment: `while(expon<current->exponent){` You need to check for a nullptr here.

Comment: @Scheff I tried only keeping the second else statement, the program still crashed, and also when i tried skipping the enclosed code line by line to see where it crashed i found out it still crashed, I don't know why

Comment: Therefore, I recommended a debugger: Executing the part (you know it will crash) step by step and watch carefully the involved variables before stepping through each line. Before doing the step, you should think what you expect to happen based on the current variable values, then do the step, and look whether the debugger did as expected.

Comment: I'm just reviewing your code (out of curiosity) and found another bad error: `Polynomial() { head=nullptr; head->next=nullptr; }` The second is access to `nullptr` -> fine for a crash. ;-)

Comment: Thank you, I will fix that and rewrite-check the code step by step

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program crashes in the Polynomial constructor which looks like this:

```
Polynomial() {
  head=nullptr;
  head->next=nullptr;
}
```

That does not work because you have set "head" to null and then after that you try to access head->next.

You cannot use head->next when head is null. Trying to do so will lead to a "segmentation fault" crash.